# Node Webkit and Web SQL error inserting JSON

Tags: javascript, jstree, node-webkit, web-sql

I'm just starting with Node-Webkit (NW.js as it is now) and I am trying to use Web-SQL to store data.

Creating the database works fine, exactly as in the examples, and generally inserting data works fine, again as in the examples. However when I come to insert a JSON object created from jsTree I am hitting trouble.

The JSON object is created using the jsTree method: `get_json('#', { 'flat': false })` and is then converted to a string with `JSON.stringify`, however when I try to insert this into a table (which exists and has the correct number of fields etc) I run across an error.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
    DBase.transaction(
        function(tx){
            var v = $("#TheTree").jstree(true).get_json('#', { 'flat': false });
            var jsv = JSON.stringify(v);
            tx.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO TheTable VALUES(null, "Default", ' + jsv + ')',
                [],
                function(tx, data){ console.log("Success"); }, 
                function(tx, error){ console.error("FAIL",error); }
            );
        };
    );
```

When returned from `JSON.stringify` the JSON is the following:

```
[{"id": "IDSTring","text": "Welcome String","icon": true,"li_attr": {"id": "tID4392"},"a_attr": {"href": "#","id": "tID4392_anchor"},"state": {"loaded": true,"opened": false,"selected": false,"disabled": false},"data": {},"children": []}]
```

If I use the same code along with any other value in place of the variable `jsv`, for example any standard string etc, there is no error and the data is inserted, however the JSON causes the following error:
`could not prepare statement (1 unrecognized token: "}") CODE: 5`.

The JSON validates at JSON Lint and can be loaded (parsed) back into jsTree with no problems, so I'm thinking that it can only be the INSERT causing the problem.

After some searching Iv tried changing the code to read:

```
'INSERT INTO TheTable VALUES(null, "Default", "' + jsv + '")'
```

and

```
'INSERT INTO TheTable VALUES(null, "Default", [' + jsv + '])'
```

with very similar errors, usually either a syntax error or "]" as an unrecognised token but always a 'Code:5'.

Any help would be gratefully received.

regards

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the parameter or use a prepared statement. Try this:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TheTable VALUES(null, "Default", ?)', [jsv], ...
```

The second parameter to `executeSql` is an array that contains all the values that will be used in place of the question marks in the query. Here are more examples: http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

Comment: Excellent job Vakata, that's what I needed! Iv been using jsTree for years now and have it going in and out of a standard SqLite database, but this is my first foray into Web SQL which is just that little bit different. Many thanks.